# Failing to implement AWS SDK in Applet

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, applet

I am trying to implement a new Java Applet Application. The JSP code I have written is simply like below:

```
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>index</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function go() {
    }
    function start() {
    }
    function error() {
    }
</script>
```

```
<h2>Örnek PDF İmza Applet</h2>
<br/>

<form id="signForm" >

    <script src="deployJava.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script><script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        var attributes = {id: 'pdfApplet',
            code: 'com.turktrust.pdfimzaapplet.PDFSigner.class',
            archive: 'PDFSelectSignSaveUploadAWSApplet.jar,looks-2.0-rc.jar, 
                      itextpdf-5.2.0.jar,bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar,
                      bcpkix-jdk15on-147.jar,
                      aws-java-sdk-1.6.12.jar,
                      com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar,
                      commons-codec-1.9.jar,commons-logging-1.1.3.jar,
                      httpclient-4.3.2.jar,httpclient-cache-4.3.2.jar,
                      httpcore-4.3.1.jar,httpmime-4.3.2.jar,
                      jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar,jackson-core-2.2.3.jar',
            jsFunctionOnSuccess: 'go',
            jsFunctionOnStart: 'start',
            jsFunctionOnError: 'error',


        };
        var parameters = {permissions: 'all'};
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.5');
        //]]>
    </script>

    <noscript>A browser with JavaScript enabled is required for this page 
              to operate properly.</noscript>
    <input type="hidden" name="ST" value="<%= 
            (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'")).
             format(new java.util.Date())%>">
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have put all specified jar files to web directory. However, I have a problem in making the web application to accept aws-java-sdk-1.6.12.jar file. When the applet starts to function, it is throwing an exception stating:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
```

Is there anything special I should do in embedding the AWS jars to applets? Or where should I check for? (I have checked the location of jars multiple times)

Comment: Provide the output of `jar -tvf aws-java-sdk-1.6.12.jar` as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21628637/edit).

Comment: I have adjusted and provided the output.

Comment: ..Where?  The edit does not contain the information I requested.

Comment: I understood you mean archive jar files. However, up to now I have never declared any extra parameter as an output jar in my previous applet projects and all of them functioned as supposed to. What should I do?